# Refresh ASP.NET VB page on same Div with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am doing a small ASP VB script to upload a file into a server.
The code actually works, and it copies the file properly, here is my asp form:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload File" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This Page form is called by a master page, and it is loaded into a Div container, this works fine.
However when I submit the form, and the actual upload happens in VB, the entire page refreshes, and not just the Div.
Here is my VB code in case you are wondering:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class fileUploader
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> 
    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            Try
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/") + FileUpload1.FileName)
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), Nothing, "hello();", True)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
            End Try
        Else
            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can you help me to get the page refreshed in its Div only?
Can I submit the form with Jquery Ajax?

**UPDATE:**
I have created an AJAX code, but now the ASP VB **code wont execute**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFile() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'fileUploader.aspx/Button1_Click',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
</script>
```

And changed the button action in the form to:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclientclick="uploadFile()" Text="Upload File" />
```

Comment: Yes you can upload files using ajax formdata or iframe. Just google Ajax file upload and you will get multiple option/ plugins.

Comment: I tried the below code, and for some reason the vb script is not getting called ... ` function uploadFile() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'fileUploader.aspx/Button1_Click',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        } `